# База данных MySQL. Проблема с внешним ключём

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня следующая ситуация: работаю с базой данный school, в которой всего есть 2 таблицы - subjects и teachers. Каждый учитель прикреплен к определенному предмету за счет первичного ключа id таблицы subjects и внешнего ключа subject_id таблицы subjects. Но вот в чем вопрос: А что, если несколько учителей ведут один и тот же предмет? То есть значение внешнего ключа subject_id таблицы teachers дублируются, это приводит к ошибке. Тогда как мне быть? Подскажите, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо!

```
use school;
create table subjects(
    id serial,
    subject_name varchar(50) not null,
    hours tinyint unsigned not null,
    primary key(id)
);

insert into subjects (subject_name, hours) values
('Математика', 35),
('Физика', 45),
('Химия', 15),
('Астрономия', 17),
('Физкультура', 25);

create table teachers(
    id serial,
    subject_id bigint unsigned not null unique,
    teacher_name varchar(50) not null,
    teacher_surname varchar(50) not null,
    age tinyint unsigned not null,
    foreign key(subject_id) references subjects(id) on delete cascade,
    primary key(id)
);

insert into teachers (subject_id, teacher_name, teacher_surname, age) values
((select id from subjects where subject_name = 'Математика'), 'Имя №1', 'Фамилия №1', 45),
((select id from subjects where subject_name = 'Математика'), 'Имя №2', 'Фамилия №2', 35),
((select id from subjects where subject_name = 'Химия'), 'Имя №3', 'Фамилия №3', 50),
((select id from subjects where subject_name = 'Астрономия'), 'Имя №4', 'Фамилия №4', 33),
((select id from subjects where subject_name = 'Физкультура'), 'Имя №5', 'Фамилия №5', 48);
```

Comment: Используй отношения многие ко многим. Учитель может вести несколько предметов и соответственно один предмет может вести тоже несколько учителей. Доп таблица с указанием ключа учителя и соответствующего ему предмета.

Comment: subject_id bigint unsigned not null **unique**, - жирным выделено лишнее в структуре БД

Answer (score 0):

Это реализуется связью "[многие ко многим](https://metanit.com/sql/tutorial/1.3.php)".

Понадобится ещё одна таблица со полями subject_id и teacher_id, где каждая строка будет устанавливать связь между преподом и предметом.